# QLever Wikidata Query not returning names

Tags: sparql, wikidata, qlever

I'm trying to surface subclasses of a Wikidata class in QLever. The query is returning QIDs but not the labels of the entities.

I've tried looking through examples on the Wikidata query service and on Qlever, but none of these are working.

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?name WHERE {
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P279 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P279/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q2424752.
      ?item rdfs:label ?name.
  MINUS { ?item a <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#LexicalSense> }
  MINUS { ?item a <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#LexicalEntry> }
  MINUS { ?item a <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#Lexeme> }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you're only selecting the `?item` in the subquery. You should put the `rdfs:label` triple pattern outside of the subquery - in addition, I'd suggest to add a filter on the language (if you want to stick to e.g. English labels only)

Comment: your property path also looks a bit odd. Why did you mix the prefixes there? It should be `(p:P279/ps:P279)+` if you want to get all subclasses

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?name WHERE {
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item (p:P279/ps:P279)+ wd:Q2424752.
  MINUS { ?item a <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#LexicalSense> }
  MINUS { ?item a <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#LexicalEntry> }
  MINUS { ?item a <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#Lexeme> }
    }
  }
      ?item rdfs:label ?name.
   FILTER(lang(?name) = "en")
}`

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful. I used the query you wrote but I'm still just getting entities with the type product, not the subclasses of it.